# Displaying each of the 24hrs of the day

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to display just the hours in 24hr format like:

> select
>   to_char(trunc(sysdate+(1/24)),'HH24:mi') from dual

But this only always returns 00:00. How can I show 01:00 to 23:00?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please tag or at least mention in your questions the software you're using (Oracle in this case, I guess?).

Comment: @Nicholas: You can edit tags yourself...

Comment: @OMG - yes, he can; he shouldn't have to, and it is not unreasonable to expect the person asking the question to tag it appropriately.  However, a first-time asker should be cut some slack.

Comment: (The reason I didn't just edit the tags was that I wasn't sure, and the reason I didn't answer is I don't use Oracle any more :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will work for Oracle 9i+:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (LEVEL / 24)), 'HH24:mi') 
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24
```

Comment: +1 ... needed something just like this for a complex query involving a result set of hours for the last day - now we'll see if the optimizer leaves it alone :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display hours, you need your date to actually contain hours. 
That means - get your brackets for TRUNC() right.

**This is good.**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (LEVEL / 24), 'HH24:mi') 
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24
```

**This is not good.**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE + (LEVEL / 24)), 'HH24:mi') 
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24
```